# Displaying Different Row in Different Section in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I've fetched This Data from API - [image: JSON Response] Which is next 7 days weather report. I want to display this as tableview where

- Date will be the as Section
- The temperature (Min / Max) as row

But If I select the section number like this -

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myList.count  // myList is an array of containing the 7 day's data 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

It printing the same row (1st data of the array) in all section. So how can I print separate weather at separate section without splitting my array?

Comment: Do not show pictures of code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to section and rows in UITableView, the key is usually **2D arrays**.
Try to create a 2D array like this:

```
myList[sectionItems][rowItems]
```

Inside this array should look something like this:

```
myList = [
 [date, minTemp, maxtemp],
 [date, minTemp, maxtemp],
 [date, minTemp, maxtemp],
 [date, minTemp, maxtemp]
]
```

So your UITableViewDelegate and DataSource functions will look like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return  myList[section].count
}
```

Above example will allow you to have **4** sections and each section will have **3** rows.

Then you can print the date on first row and the rest on other rows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = UITableViewCell()                    
  cell.textLabel.text = myList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```